# JS Google Charts can't change pie background color

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I tried this code, but my pie bg color is still blue.. could you advise something?

```
  var options = {

  chart: {
  backgroundColor: 'brown', // for the area outside the chartArea
  chartArea: {
  backgroundColor: 'green'
}
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

`chartArea` is not a valid key... Just use `backgroundColor`.

```
var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'brown',
    chartArea: {
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, your code change bg color of div, but I need to change bg colors of graphic (pie). Is it possible?

Comment: @WEBSITEFREELANCE, do you mean the pie 'slices'? If so, then yes: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_charts.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @WEBSITEFREELANCE, no problem.
If my answer was helpful, please consider marking my answer as accepted.
Thanks!